# Should my Kendo webforms be in same project as WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0, kendo-ui

I created a WCF project (WCF Service Application) and I added a method that returns test JSON data. In that same project, I created a *Reports* folder and, within that folder, I created a webform (Report.aspx) which includes a JS file (which does the WCF calls) and some html, which is ultimately, a simple kendo donut. There's no codebehind. I'm including the WCF code so I don't get downvote for not having code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
UriTemplate = "ShowValues")]
System.IO.Stream ShowValues();
```

and

```
public System.IO.Stream ShowValues()
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Penetration", typeof(int));
  DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
  row["Penetration"] = 97;
  DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
  row2["Penetration"] = 3;
  dt.Rows.Add(row);
  dt.Rows.Add(row2);
  return Conversions.ConvertToJson(dt);
}
```

Everything here works fine; the WCF call through the browser returns the correct data and the JS call consumes that data correctly. In other words, the simple kendo donut is displayed. In this scenario, everything is in the same project and everything works fine.

Since I don't want to have my kendo webform and my WCF in the same project, I created an ASP.Net Empty Web Application that will only have Report.aspx. So after creating the project, I did what I did in the first project: I created *Reports* folder and copied everything from one folder to the other (Report.aspx & associated files, Kendo files, etc).

For some reason, even though the WCF call is made (it stops at breakpoint), the graphics aren't shown. The only difference is that the new project includes all the files and folders of a project (web.config, bin/obj/other folders, csproj, etc). But aside from that, both Reports folders are exactly the same.

So my question is: should these files be in the same project as the WCF service? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably hit the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). To check this inspect your browser developer tools (the network tab).

Try using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or enabling [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) if you don't want to have your forms in the same project as the WCF service.

Comment: Thanks. But I had already enabled cross-domain script access in web.config. In any case, should the reports be within the same project or in their own project?

Comment: Also, there are no issues with the jquery call in Project1 calling the WCF service in Project2. During debugging, the debugger hits the WCF method breakpoint while loading the report. The problem would then be the Kendo controls.

Comment: Did you check your browser developer tools for any errors?

Comment: which browser developer tools?

Comment: Your browser developer tools. Hitting F12 will open them in most browsers.

Comment: I thought you were referring to some add-in for VS. I never thought to check firebug since the wcf call was actually being processed.

Comment: I checked DevTools and it's indeed blocking cross-origin requests. So you're right about that. My question is, since the WCF service in localhost:100 is actually processing the call from localhost:200, where is the block occurring?